# How to get the total number of likes & comments about particular post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I want to get the total number of like & comments for a particular post on my website, for eg. if my website has 100 pages, I integrate facebook like button on every page, how can i get the number of likes related to that page or post? I have take a look a GRAPH API, but i did n't find any thing relating to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this
[Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)

simply use this javascript code. (change the url)

```
 FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.facebook.com"'
            }, function(response){});
```